# Dict Comprehension python from list of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of lists and I am trying to make a dictionary from the lists.  I know how to do it using this method.
[Creating a dictionary with list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858096/creating-a-dictionary-with-list-of-lists-in-python)

What I am trying to do is build the list using the elements in the first list as the keys and the rest of the items with the same index would be the list of values.  But I can't figure out where to start. Each list is the same length but the length of the lists vary

```
exampleList = [['first','second','third'],['A','B','C'], ['1','2','3']]

resultDict = {'first':['A','1'],'second':['B','2'],'third':['C','3']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care of the case when `exampleList` could be of any length..

```
exampleList = [['first','second','third'],['A','B','C'], ['1','2','3'],[4,5,6]]

z=list(zip(*exampleList[1:]))
d={k:list(z[i])  for i,k in enumerate(exampleList[0])}
print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'first': ['A', '1', 4], 'second': ['B', '2', 5], 'third': ['C', '3', 6]}
```

Comment: I just added that to the description because the length of the lists can vary.

Answer (score 3):

Unpack the values using `zip(*exampleList)` and create a dictionary using key value pair.

```
dicta = {k:[a, b] for k, a, b in zip(*exampleList)}
print(dicta)
# {'first': ['A', '1'], 'second': ['B', '2'], 'third': ['C', '3']}
```

If **more** lists:

```
dicta = {k:[*a] for k, *a in zip(*exampleList)}
# {'first': ['A', '1', 4], 'second': ['B', '2', 5], 'third': ['C', '3', 6]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unpacking and using `zip` followed by a dict comprehension to get the mapping with first elements seems readable.

```
result_dict = {first: rest for first, *rest in zip(*exampleList)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about lists vs tuples, it's as simple as using `zip` twice:

```
result_dict = dict(zip(example_list[0], zip(*example_list[1:])))
```

Otherwise, you'll need to through in a call to `map`:

```
result_dict = dict(zip(example_list[0], map(list, zip(*example_list[1:]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function might be what you are looking for.

```
exampleList = [['first','second','third'],['A','B','C'], ['1','2','3']]
d = {x: [y, z] for x, y, z in zip(*exampleList)}
print(d)
#{'first': ['A', '1'], 'second': ['B', '2'], 'third': ['C', '3']}
```