# How can I transform a list of multiple lists into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains multiple lists and I want to transform the first list into keys and the subsequent lists into values, without the use of pandas.

Example:

```
list = [[a, b, c],[1 ,2, 3], [4, 5, 6]....]
```

How can I transform that into this:

```
dict = {a: [1, 4, 7], b: [2, 5, 8].....}
```

Comment: Are all the lists of the same size?

Comment: Also have you written any code that can help us understand what you have tried?

Comment: Learn to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) with [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a dictionary with list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858096/creating-a-dictionary-with-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
dct = {l[0]: list(l[1:]) for l in zip(*lst)}
# {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

This makes use of `zip()` and the unpacking operator `*` to "rotate" the list `lst` (turn it into `[['a', 1, 4], ['b', 2, 5], ['c', 3, 6]]`). This is a fairly common idiom.

Then we just iterate over each of those sublists in a dict comprehension, assign the zeroth element as the key, and the rest of the elements as the value.

Note that by default `zip()` returns tuples instead of lists, so we have to typecast `l[1:]` to a `list` if we want to be able to modify it later. This may not be necessary in your use case.